# Conditional array to calculate percentiles

Tags: arrays, excel, conditional-statements, percentile

I have some data as follows:

```
    val   crit  perc
0.415605498 1   perc1
0.475426007 1   perc1
0.418621318 1   perc1
0.51608229  1   perc1
0.452307882 1   perc1
0.496691416 1   perc1
0.402689126 1   perc1
0.494381345 1   perc1
0.532406777 1   perc1
0.839352016 2   perc2
0.618221702 2   perc2
0.83947033  2   perc2
0.621734007 2   perc2
0.548656662 2   perc2
0.711919796 2   perc2
0.758178085 2   perc2
0.820954467 2   perc2
0.478645786 2   perc2
0.848323655 2   perc2
0.844986383 2   perc2
0.418155292 2   perc2
1.182637063 3   perc3
1.248876472 3   perc3
1.218368809 3   perc3
0.664934398 3   perc3
0.951692853 3   perc3
0.848111264 3   perc3
0.58887439  3   perc3
0.931530464 3   perc3
0.676314176 3   perc3
1.270797783 3   perc3
```

I'm trying to use the percentile.inc() function to calculate the 5th percentile for each level of *crit* (since I have categorized the variable *var* into classes).

I've tried to use `{=PERCENTILE.INC(IF($B$2:$B$32=1,$A$2:$A$32,IF($B$2:$B$32=2,$A$2:$A$32,IF($B$2:$B$32=3,$A$2:$A$32,""))),0.05)}` but all it does is calculate the percentile for the whole array and does not give me back the conditional percentiles.

Any help would be most welcome (and FYI, I've got to do this on 26000 rows with 20 levels of *crit*)!

Comment: You are trying to get three answers out one formula. I suggest you need the same (modified) formula in three cells to separate the results for the three crit values.

Have been trying a modified formula for you, will get there.

BTW, your last argument 0.05 = the 5th percentile, not the 0.05th percentile.

Comment: Thanks for someone solved it already!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This worked for me. I have the following layout:

[image]

And I used the following formula in G3:

```
=PERCENTILE.INC(IF(B:B=F3,A:A),0.05)
```

This is an Array formula, so enter with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`.
Drag down as suited.

Comment: It seems to work, but I should have specified that I'd like it to give me a result in the shape of my table... With values associated to each row. Any smart way to do that?

Comment: So in your perc column, you want to have the percentile?

Comment: Exactly! Small detail, probably, but it would help for what I have to do next (and your formula worked perfectly on the whole dataset btw).

Comment: What you could do is use this formula in C2 (assuming you have headers) and drag down : `=PERCENTILE.INC(IF(B:B=B2,A:A),0.05)`

Comment: If you have a lot of data, it could be that the formula will be a bit slow. You can improve the speed by avoiding the full column reference `A:A` and `B:B` and replace it by the actual amount of rows you have like this: replace `A:A` with `A$2:A$26000` and `B:B` with `B$2:B$26000`

Comment: Yes, it's processing like crazy with the A:A and B:B solution... A lot smoother with the actual array. Thank you very much!