# Excel: get all values from column A where column B equals selected value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have an excel with all teams and their respective team members.

In the same excel file I have a sheet where you can select a team, and based on the value I should fill out all of that team's members in a cell on that sheet.

Currently I have a solution where the user will need to filter the list of members to only include the members of his/her team with the following function:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,'Team members'!A2:A13)
```

I now need to edit this formula to make sure I only get members of a selected team (instead of a hard coded one).

Team Members Sheet:

[image: Team Members]

In this second sheet (CoverSheet) the user needs to select one of the teams from the screenshot above in cell A2. Based on the value in A2 the result in B2 should change to list all the team members.

[image]

EDIT

---

I have just tried out the solution provided below but when I try it on the actual Excel that's being used I get a #VALUE! error because the total length of the result would go over a certain number of characters. I assume this based on the remarks in this article: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXTJOIN-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c

Does anyone have an idea of how to work around this?

Comment: Will you be able to add a screenshot here. Am having trouble opening the link

Comment: @GowthamShiva I have added some screenshots, please let me know if they are not clear!

Comment: If i select Team A, i should get member a-1 and member a-7 in the same cell (B2)?

Comment: @GowthamShiva Ideally yes, if it's absolutely not possible it suffices if I can find a way to replace the list of team members from another source and only edit the ranges in formulas, for example.

Comment: Concatenate doesn't accept arrays so I don't see how you can get it into one column  without VBA but getting a filtered list is easy enough: http://www.exceltactics.com/make-filtered-list-sub-arrays-excel-using-small/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have the formula `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,'Team members'!A2:A13)` in your question I assume you are using Excel 2016 in which case we can modify this formula to work for what you need I think. I do not have 2016 or office 365 so I can not test.

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,If('Team Members'!B2:B13='CoverSheet'!B1,'Team members'!A2:A13,"")
```

You will need to hit Ctrl + Shift + Enter to make this work. Thanks @Michael for pointing that out.

Comment: Just need to enter it as an array formula using `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`

Comment: Thank you @Michael I was unaware about the array formula part being needed as I do not have access to 2016 or office 365 to test.

Comment: @ChadPortman Thank you for your answer, your solution worked in combination with Michael's comment. If I just press ENTER instead of CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER I just get the entire collection of team members.

Comment: Super glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the materix formulas applied at the function TEXTJOIN.
Something like:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(B:B=F3,A:A))
```

Instead of press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, you have to put the cursor on "B:B" and then hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. This will add curly brackets to your formula and transform it in a [matrix formula](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi4u-e2x4jTAhUCVhQKHQluAiQQFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.office.com%2Fen-us%2Farticle%2FGuidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7&usg=AFQjCNGu0SjbTuJ1zb4iwLIHieJ7DgP0Hw&bvm=bv.151325232,d.bGs).

With the spreadsheet

```
+---+---------+--------+
|   |    A    |   B    |
+---+---------+--------+
| 1 | User    | Team   |
| 2 | User 01 | Team 1 |
| 3 | User 02 | Team 1 |
| 4 | User 03 | Team 2 |
| 5 | User 04 | Team 3 |
+---+---------+--------+
```

Where F3 contain the Team name (i.e. "Team 1").
I don't have access to Excel 2016 at the moment so I can't be more practical.

Please consider [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34124898/conditional-array-to-calculate-percentiles) that you coluld apply to your formula.